# Debian Jessie not working hot plug with usb modem sierra 802

Tags: usb, debian, modem

When I connect modem befour PC start all works fine. But when connect to working PC have bug.

Have no use any drivers from other place all work on default debian jessie repositories.

Here dmesg:

```
171.342776] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[  171.528837] usb 2-5: USB disconnect, device number 2
[  171.998784] usb 2-5: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[  172.131651] usb 2-5: New USB device found, idVendor=1199, idProduct=0029
[  172.131658] usb 2-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  172.131664] usb 2-5: Product: Sierra Wireless Tethered Hotspot
[  172.131668] usb 2-5: Manufacturer: Linux 2.6.28.10-arm1 with pxa3xx_u2d
[  172.185784] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial
[  172.185822] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[  172.185851] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
[  172.210624] usbcore: registered new interface driver sierra
[  172.210668] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for Sierra USB modem
[  172.210734] sierra 2-5:1.0: Sierra USB modem converter detected
[  172.211174] usb 2-5: Sierra USB modem converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[  172.211984] sierra 2-5:1.1: Sierra USB modem converter detected
[  172.212400] usb 2-5: Sierra USB modem converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[  172.277188] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ether
[  172.285339] sierra ttyUSB0: sierra_submit_rx_urbs: submit urb failed: -8
[  172.285346] sierra ttyUSB0: sierra_submit_rx_urbs: submit urb failed: -8
[  172.285350] sierra ttyUSB0: sierra_submit_rx_urbs: submit urb failed: -8
[  172.285354] sierra ttyUSB0: sierra_submit_rx_urbs: submit urb failed: -8
[  172.285827] sierra ttyUSB0: sierra_submit_rx_urbs: submit urb failed: -8
[  172.285831] sierra ttyUSB0: sierra_submit_rx_urbs: submit urb failed: -8
[  172.285835] sierra ttyUSB0: sierra_submit_rx_urbs: submit urb failed: -8
[  172.285838] sierra ttyUSB0: sierra_submit_rx_urbs: submit urb failed: -8
[  172.286198] sierra ttyUSB0: sierra_submit_rx_urbs: submit urb failed: -8
[  172.286202] sierra ttyUSB0: sierra_submit_rx_urbs: submit urb failed: -8
[  172.286205] sierra ttyUSB0: sierra_submit_rx_urbs: submit urb failed: -8
[  172.286208] sierra ttyUSB0: sierra_submit_rx_urbs: submit urb failed: -8
[  172.286601] sierra ttyUSB0: sierra_submit_rx_urbs: submit urb failed: -8
[  172.286608] sierra ttyUSB0: sierra_submit_rx_urbs: submit urb failed: -8
[  172.286612] sierra ttyUSB0: sierra_submit_rx_urbs: submit urb failed: -8
[  172.286615] sierra ttyUSB0: sierra_submit_rx_urbs: submit urb failed: -8
[  172.286947] sierra ttyUSB0: sierra_submit_rx_urbs: submit urb failed: -8
[  172.286953] sierra ttyUSB0: sierra_submit_rx_urbs: submit urb failed: -8
[  172.286958] sierra ttyUSB0: sierra_submit_rx_urbs: submit urb failed: -8
[  172.286963] sierra ttyUSB0: sierra_submit_rx_urbs: submit urb failed: -8
[  172.287325] sierra ttyUSB0: sierra_submit_rx_urbs: submit urb failed: -8
[  172.287333] sierra ttyUSB0: sierra_submit_rx_urbs: submit urb failed: -8
[  172.287338] sierra ttyUSB0: sierra_submit_rx_urbs: submit urb failed: -8
[  172.287343] sierra ttyUSB0: sierra_submit_rx_urbs: submit urb failed: -8
```

Answer (score 0):

Have found [this article](http://archimedesnewton.com/2012/12/04/sierra-wireless-overdrive-pro-3g4g-mobile-hotspot-802s-with-linuxmint-13-maya/):

> In the good sequence, `cdc_ether` is loaded first and lays claim to the
>   device. The new `eth1` interface is configured and all is well. After
>   doing some research, I decided to give something a go. What if we just
>   disabled the sierra driver? It seemed like this latest Sierra Wireless
>   device didn’t really need that driver as it could communicate via USB
>   CDC. What could it hurt? Nothing, I figured, so I opened up
>   `/etc/modeprobe.d/blacklist.conf` (don’t forget to invoke `vi` with `sudo`!)
>   and went to work. Here’s what I added at the bottom.
>
> ```
> # added 2012-12-04 - prevent sierra USB driver from loading 
> blacklist sierra
> ```